# w3schools PHP AJAX Live search,

Tags: php, ajax, livesearch

As I am starting to use php,xml and all that fun.

In the php [code from this example at w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp), I've added a variable:

```
//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
```

//added variable

```
    $w=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('w');
```

.

```
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>
```

//added var in loop with some text as well:

```
         <p>textLabel: " . $w->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . " </p>";
```

My xml contain something like this:

```
<title>1</title>
<url>5</url>
<w></w>
```

I want to run a check whether the variable 'w' is empty or not, in my case it's enough to test for an integer, maybe like this?:

```
if (is_int($w)) {
    # code...
  }
```

I try to modify the php code with if statements, but I've only generated unexpected if_t errors, whenever I trid to insert it.

The desired end result is to display the labelText and the  value if there is an int in , else, display nothing.

> Edit

With `var_dump()` on my variables I was figuring out what was going on. Empty nodes returns NULL, so that was nice to know.

I proceeded with inserting if statement:

```
if ($c->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
  //find a name matching the search text
  if (stristr($c->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
    if ($hint=="") {
      //new if statement to check if node value is NULL
      if (is_null($f->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue)) {
          $lbl="";
      } else{$lbl='some text to display or not';
      }

      $hint=
```

then I concatenated $lbl where I wanted the text, and it worked!

I'm sure there is a better aproach, but with my days of programming exp I was quite happy to figure it out! Appriciate tips to do it in a nicer way though :)

Comment: Show us please how do you add your `if`

Comment: I tried to figure out how to show it, and that was making me finding a way, edited on my solution for now.